# Posting form submissions with the KOBO REST API

Tags: c#, api

I'm having a little trouble posting form submissions from C# to a KOBO Server (https://kf.kobotoolbox.org). The response I get is 'Bad Gateway'.

Here's my code:

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/submissions"); 
    //var client = new RestClient("https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms/{pk}/labels");       
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("a_user", "alpha9876");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("pk", "31037");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("tags", "tag1, tag2");

   // client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("format", "xls"); 

    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("url", "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/projects/1");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("owner", "https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/users/ona");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("name", "project 1");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("date_created", "2013-07-24T13:37:39Z");
    //client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("date_modified", "2013-07-24T13:37:39Z");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    request.AddHeader("header", "xml");                      
    request.Resource = "C:\\Users\\Susan\\Desktop\\xmltest\\form_linkage_parentform.xml";
```

Could anyone help with a sample snippet of what the C# code for making this POST HTTP request would probably look like? Based on this: https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using CSV files (https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms) as follows:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms/{pk}/csv_import");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user_name", "password");
client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("pk", "31045");
string file_path = Server.MapPath("~/myform.csv");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddFile("csv_file", file_path);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```